# Why is the reflection of a vector on a line, twice the projection of the vector minus the vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am working through a linear algebra text and I am doing exercises in a chapter dealing with linear transformations and linear functions. I am trying to come up with the transformation matrix for a vector reflected on a line in two-dimensional space. Please try to the answer the question without change of basis or eigenvalues as I have not reached that chapter. I am confident this does not warrant complicated trigonometry either.

So far I have projected the basis vectors of the space onto the line and found an orthogonal line in search of a solution. I am not sure where to go from here. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried drawing a diagram containing any arbitrary vector and line of reflection?  [Here](https://puu.sh/EEBb3.png) is a rough sketch.

Comment: @AndrewChin yes, I just came to the geometric conclusion from a similar drawing. Thank you for confirming my findings. Now I am constructing a projection matrix by first finding a basis for the line and projecting the basis vectors on it. Then I should be able to find the reflection matrix by following the equation for a reflection. Is this correct?

Comment: Sounds like the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a rohumbus  $ABCD$ with the ceneter point $O$

Let  the diagonal $AC$ being the line and the vector $AB$ being reflected to the vetor $AD.$

The projection is vector $AO$ which is half of vectro $AC.$

The reflection vector $AD$ is equal to the vector $BC$ and we have $$BC=AC-AB =2AO -AB$$